# Why does pthread_exit() in rare cases cause a SEGV when called after pthread_detach()?

Tags: c++, pthreads, centos, race-condition, segmentation-fault

I am getting a SEGV in C++ that I cannot easily reproduce (it occurs in about one in 100,000 test runs) in my call to `pthread_join()` as my application is shutting down.  I checked the value of errno and it is zero.  This is running on Centos v4.

Under what conditions would `pthread_join()` get a SEGV? This might be some kind of race condition since it is extremely rare.  One person suggests I should not be calling pthread_detach() and pthread_exit(), but I am not clear on why.

My first working hypothesis was that `pthread_join()` is being called while `pthread_exit()` is still running in the other thread and that this somehow leads to a SEGV, but many have stated this is not an issue.

The failing code getting SEGV in the main thread during application exit looks roughly like this (with error return code checking omitted for brevity):

```
// During application startup, this function is called to create the child thread:

return_val = pthread_create(&_threadId, &attr,
                            (void *(*)(void *))initialize,
                            (void *)this);

// Apparently this next line is the issue:
return_val = pthread_detach(_threadId);

// Later during exit the following code is executed in the main thread:

// This main thread waits for the child thread exit request to finish:

// Release condition so child thread will exit:
releaseCond(mtx(), startCond(), &startCount);

// Wait until the child thread is done exiting so we don't delete memory it is
// using while it is shutting down.
waitOnCond(mtx(), endCond(), &endCount, 0);
// The above wait completes at the point that the child thread is about
// to call pthread_exit().

// It is unspecified whether a thread that has exited but remains unjoined
// counts against {PTHREAD_THREADS_MAX}, hence we must do pthread_join() to
// avoid possibly leaking the threads we destroy.
pthread_join(_threadId, NULL); // SEGV in here!!!
```

The child thread which is being joined on exit runs the following code which begins at the point above where `releaseCond()` is called in the main thread:

```
// Wait for main thread to tell us to exit:
waitOnCond(mtx(), startCond(), &startCount);

// Tell the main thread we are done so it will do pthread_join():
releaseCond(mtx(), endCond(), &endCount);
// At this point the main thread could call pthread_join() while we 
// call pthread_exit().

pthread_exit(NULL);
```

The thread appeared to come up properly and no error codes were produced during its creation during application startup and the thread performed its task correctly which took around five seconds before the application exited.

What might cause this rare SEGV to occur and how might I program defensively against it.  One claim is that my call to pthread_detach() is the issue, if so, how should my code be corrected.

Comment: Have you checked the local documentation for your pthread_join() not all are standard compliant you may have to pass a non NULL pointer.

Comment: How does the "child thread" know when to call that exit code? How does that exit code get invoked?

Comment: Centos 4?  Very retro.  LinuxThreads or NPTL?

Comment: @Loki man pthread_join allows NULL pointer.

Comment: @user315052 Child knows because main thread set state variable to exit and then releases the start condition so child will check the state variale to see what action is requested. I omitted this for brevity.  The exit code is invoked by the destructor of object that manages the child thread from the main thread.

Comment: @pilcrow How do I determine whether Centos 4 has native Posix or Linux threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming:

1. `pthread_create` returns zero (you are checking it, right?)
2. `attr` is a valid `pthread_attr_t` object (How are you creating it?  Why not just pass NULL instead?)
3. `attr` does not specify that the thread is to be created detached
4. You did not call `pthread_detach` or `pthread_join` on the thread somewhere else

...then it is "impossible" for `pthread_join` to fail, and you either have some other memory corruption or a bug in your runtime.

[update]

The RATIONALE section for [`pthread_detach`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_detach.html) says:

> The *pthread_join*() or *pthread_detach*() functions should eventually be
>   called for every thread that is created so that storage associated
>   with the thread may be reclaimed.

Although it does not say these are mutually exclusive, the [`pthread_join` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) specifies:

> The behavior is undefined if the value specified by the *thread*
>   argument to *pthread_join*() does not refer to a joinable thread.

I am having trouble finding the exact wording that says a detached thread is not joinable, but I am pretty sure it is true.

So, either call `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach`, but not both.

Comment: 1) Checking return value is zero.
2) It is valid, using `pthread_attr_init(&attr);` and `pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, stackSize);` to 64 MB stack size.
3) Nothing else is in Attr, all else is defaulted.
4) I *did* call `pthread_detach(_threadId);` soon after `pthread_create()`.

So how should I update to correct this?

Comment: You do not need to join a detached thread; to do so is an error.  I will update my answer with a reference when I get home...

Comment: I'm also surprised that there's not a more explicit description of what a "joinable thread" is in the POSIX docs (or at least one that's easier to find).  Another bit of info that may be relevant is in the doc for `pthread_attr_getdetachstate()`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_getdetachstate.html#  which says "If the thread is created detached, then use of the ID of the newly created thread by the pthread_detach() or pthread_join() function is an error"

Answer (score 0):

If you read the standards documentation for [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) and [pthread_exit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_exit.html) and related pages, the join suspends execution "until the target thread terminates", and the thread calling pthread_exit doesn't terminate until it's done calling pthread_exit, so what you're worried about can't be the problem.

You may have corrupted memory somewhere (as Nemo suggests), or called pthread_exit from a cleanup handler (as user315052 suggests), or something else. But it's not "a race condition between pthread_join() and pthread_exit()", unless you're on a buggy or non-compliant implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is insufficient information to fully diagnose your problem. I concur with the other posted answers that the problem is more likely undefined behavior in your code than a race condition between `pthread_join` and `pthread_exit`. But I would also agree the existence of such a race would constitute a bug in the `pthread` library implementation.

Regarding `pthread_join`:

```
return_val = pthread_create(&_threadId, &attr,
                            (void *(*)(void *))initialize,
                            (void *)this);
//...
pthread_join(_threadId, NULL); // SEGV in here!!!
```

It looks like the join is in a class. This opens up the possibility that the object could be deleted while `main` is trying to do the join. If `pthread_join` is accessing freed memory, the result is undefined behavior. I am leaning towards this possibility, since accessing freed memory is very often undetected.

Regarding `pthread_exit`: The man page on Linux, and the POSIX spec state:

> An implicit call to pthread_exit() is made when a thread other than the thread in which main() was first invoked returns from the start routine that was used to create it. The function's return value shall serve as the thread's exit status.
>
> The behavior of pthread_exit() is undefined if called from a cancellation cleanup handler or destructor function that was invoked as a result of either an implicit or explicit call to pthread_exit().

If the `pthread_exit` call is made in a cleanup handler, you will have undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, this is in a class, the ctor does the pthread_create() and the dtor does the pthread_join().